# Bitmap to base64

Tags: vb.net

How can I turn a bitmap into a base64 string? This is what i tried so far :

```
    Private Function solve_captcha(image As Bitmap) As String
    Dim encode_type As ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        image.Save(ms, encode_type)
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray
        Dim base64str As String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
        Clipboard.SetText(base64str)
        MsgBox(base64str)
    End Using
End Function
```

But the output is allways a black image...

Comment: "output is always a black image"...how and where are you displaying the base64 encoded image? To display it, you'd have to decode it back to binary - base64 is a string format, so you can't say that the direct output of that is a black image.

Comment: Dim base64str As String that means it's a string, you need pixels (bytes). Convert it back.

Comment: @ADyson I'm using a website to decode the base64 string generated by my code. Thats how I know the output is a black image.

Comment: @CruleD But I want the output to be a string. (i want to convert an image to a base64 string)

Comment: are you certain the bitmap is valid in the first place? How are you reading data into the `bitmap` object you send to your function?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I'm sure. I allready tried saving it to my pc before running the function to make sure everything is fine.

Comment: And this result is true of any arbitrary bitmap you choose to process through this function, or just specific ones? How many have you tested? Also just because you saved it to your PC ok doesn't necessarily prove everything - read my comment again: how are you reading the bitmap data into your VB code?

Comment: @ADyson I'm taking the image from a website using a webbrowser. I havent tried another bitmap, but I dont see the point tbh since the bitmap is containing the right image for sure.

Comment: "I'm taking the image from a website"...yes but, for the 3rd time, **how**?  _Show your code_ then we know for sure. Just because you can see it on screen in Windows doesn't mean you imported the data correctly into your application. As for not seeing the point in using a different image, I think if you've got a problem with your output data, the first thing you do is test it with some different input data, so you can tell if the problem is the data or the code. That's step no. 1 in the Debugging for Dummies manual.